# Show data from joined table on form area of screen

Tags: screen, acumatica

I have a formtab screen with a primary view that was originally a single table. I added a join to it and I would like to display a field from the joined table on the screen.  How do I make the joined table's data available on the page designer?

I found some other examples and I was playing with this when I received your latest comment.  I added this definition to my DAC. This should give me access to the ARPayment status?

```
    #region PmtStatus
    [PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true, BqlField = typeof(ARPayment.status))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Payment Status")]
    [ARDocStatus.List]
    public virtual String PmtStatus { get; set; }
    public abstract class pmtStatus : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Hello Jerry, you can try like this "DACName__FieldName"

Comment: Do I have to create an entry in my DAC referring to the joined DAC or just manually change the field on the page?

Comment: manually you can change, if possible can you paste your BQL and let me know field name you need in UI

Comment: I am joining to ARPayment and I want to retrieve the status.  I will update the question with the code shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fields from the joined table of your view by including the DAC name and field name with a double underscore (**DAC__Field**). So if your DAC is **ARPayment** and the field is **Status** then the date field value is **ARPayment__Status** as shown below. This is defined in your aspx page.

```
<PXDropDown ID="edARPaymentStatus" runat="server" DataField="ARPayment__Status"/>
```